# Can't count certain sign appeared in each cell

Tags: excel, vba, split, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a macro which is supposed to check for a number of range to find out if there are multiple items separated by semicolon `;` within certain cells. If it finds one then the macro will count how many times that sign ***`;`*** has appeared in each cell:

For example, in Range("A1") that sign has appeared 3 times:

```
apple;orange;guava;malta
```

I've tried so far:

```
Sub DistributeItemsToColumns()
    Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In Range("A1:L4")
        If InStr(cel, ";") > 0 Then
            Debug.Print cel  'can't think further
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: Read up on `Text To Columns` :) No loop required. In fact record a macro and then `Select the relevant Column ==> Data tab ==> Text To Columns`.

Comment: I need to know first whether the content of any cell having more than one ***";"***. I can't understand the logic to apply. I know I can use len property but how?

Comment: You do not need to know if the cell contains ";" or not. If it is present, text to columns will take care of it, else it will leave the cell alone...

Comment: you can see that I've included vba tag to do the operation using maco. Thanks.

Comment: And you can see that in my first comment, I mentioned that you can record a macro. Give it a try and you will get the code that you seek :)

Comment: I've edited my post to make it clearer the result I'm after. Thanks.

Comment: So you do not want to split the words? Just count the number of occurances of ";"?

Comment: I'm puzzled with what you want, the method @SiddharthRout described does exactly what the answer below does. Or is the key here to skip the single values?

Comment: Yes, the tricky part always get someone puzzled. SiddharthRout suggested me to go for excel in the first place. Check out the title of this post to understand what I expected @JvdV.

Comment: **[1]** As far as the title of the question goes, it has been changed so many times. See the unedited version. The original title was "Can't split content of different cells and rearrange them to columns conditionally" **[2]** There is nothing tricky about what you asked. It is a simple question. Excel has inbuilt `.TextToColumns`. If you would have recorded a macro like I suggested in the 1st comment, you would have got a 1-2 line code which you could have edited to get what you wanted. You do not need a loop to split the text (which is what you originally wanted)

Comment: **[3]** VBA is not on the verge of extinction. It is a myth. And I am not sure which developers you are talking about who have lost hope :D Look around in the VBA tag, does it look like people have given up hope? **[4]** As far as "ability" is concerned, let's not go down that road... Feel free to go ahead with the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, arr As Variant
    Dim NumberOfOccu As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Find last row of column A
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Loop from row 1 to lastrow
        For i = 1 To LastRow

            If InStr(.Range("A" & i).Value, ";") Then
                'Number of characters
                NumberOfOccu = InStr(.Range("A" & i).Value, ";")
                arr = Split(.Range("A" & i).Value, ";")
                .Range("C" & i).Resize(, UBound(arr) + 1) = arr

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it does the job perfectly. Could you tell me how can I count the occurrences of this signs ***`;`*** in each cell?